# How I can parse substring with regular expression ?

Tags: c#, regex

My example non-parsed data is

```
"8$154#3$021308831#7$NAME SURNAME#11$2166220160#10$5383237309#52$05408166#"
```

I want to parse data that is between $ and # strings.
I want to see result like that;

Between `8$` and `#` -> My data is `154`,
Between `3$` and `#` -> My data is `021308831`,
Between `7$` and `#` -> My data is `NAME SURNAME`,
Between `11$` and `#` -> My data is `2166220160`,
Between `10$` and `#` -> My data is `5383237309`,
Between `52$` and `#` -> My data is `05408166`.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: will the data ever contain #? can # be escaped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(\d+\$)(.*?)#
```

[See it on Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/AzqlcgLZx5)

You will find the first part (e.g. `8$`) in the capturing group 1 and the according data in the group 2.

The brackets are responsible, that the result is sotred in those capturing groups. The `\d+` will match at least one digit. The `.*?` is a lazy match for everything till the next `#`.

Comment: good answer, I've incorporated it into some c# code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can split into array based on `#`.
With

```
String[] entries = data.Split('#');
```

you will get an arrays with "8$154", "3$021308831", etc.

Now you just work with the entries and split each one at the dollar sign:

```
String[] tmp = entries[0].Split('$');
```

So you get

```
tmp[0] = "8";
tmp[1] = "154";
```

Build in some checks and you will be happy. No need for regex here I suppose.

If you have "8$15$4#3$021308831" then you will get in `tmp`:

```
tmp[0] = "8"; // your key!
tmp[1] = "15"; // data part
tmp[2] = "4"; // data part ($ is missing!)
```

So you would have to concat all tmp above index 1:

```
StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 1; i < tmp.Length; i++)
{
    if(i > 1) value.Append("$");
    value.Append(tmp[i]);
}
```

Comment: this would work but doesen't use a regular expression, what happens id $ appears in the body of the data?

Comment: How will you distinguish `$` in data from a seperator `$`?

Comment: If you say the first `$` is always the seperator then you will have to concat tmp[1] and tmp[1+n] if they exists. Not sure which of the regex answers will do this. See edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "8$154#3$021308831#7$NAME SURNAME#11$2166220160#10$5383237309#52$05408166#";
        string[] values = text.Split('$', '#');
        for (var i = 0; i < values.Length - 1; i = i + 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Between " + values[i] + "$ and # -> My data is " + values[i+1]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, taking [stema](https://stackoverflow.com/users/626273/stema)'s expression, which works.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string nonParsed = "8$...";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(nonparsed, @"(\d+\$)(.*?)#");

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
    Match match = matches[i];

    result.AppendFormat("Between {0} and #-> My data is {1}")
        match.Groups[1].Value,
        match.Groups[2].Value);

    if (i < matches.Count - 1)
    {
        result.AppendLine(",");
    }
    else
    {
        result.Append(".");
    }
}

return result.ToString();
```

Thanks to [stema](https://stackoverflow.com/users/626273/stema), this copes with the `$` repeating within the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex this should do it.

```
\$([\w\d\s]+)\#
```

Answer (score 0):

This will match betweel $ and #:

```
\$(.*?)#
```